# My c program is not giving any result.pls help everyone

Tags: c, loops, factorial

i have written a program which is not giving proper result.

```
main()
{
    int i=1,n,s=1;
    printf("enter the value of n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    while(i<=n) 
    {
         s=s*i;
         i++;
         if (i==n+1)
         {
             break; 
         }
    }
    printf("factorial of n=",s);
}
```

it is giving the result as shown in the picture below.
[image]

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: You don't print the value of `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
printf("factorial of n=%d\n",s);
                       ^^
```

And this code snippet

```
     if (i==n+1)
     {
         break; 
     }
```

is redundant and may be removed.

You could write the loop simpler. For example

```
while ( n > 1 ) s *= n--;
```

without a need to use one more variable `i`.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is in this line:

```
printf("factorial of n=",s);
```

This outputs `factorial of n=`, but it does not simply concatenate the value of `s`, and there is no placeholder for `s`, so you actually have too many parameters.

You need a placeholder for the `int` output:

```
printf("factorial of n=%d",s);
```

Without it, your program exits with an error (status 15, when 0 would be normal).

Also, (as Vlad pointed out in his answer) the `if (i==n+1) { ... }` block is redundant, as your `while` loop will already exit when `i > n`.